# Laravel Relationship with Model

Tags: laravel, api, relationship

I have made all Relationships and they work. I just wanted to add it, to my API with this code

```
$devices = Device::with(['Devicemodel' => function($query)
{
  $query->with(['Manufacture', 'Devicetype']);
}])
```

Because Device has a relationship with Devicemodel. This works. And Devicemodel has a relationship with Manufacture and Devicetype. But i get returned NULL. Why?

EDIT:

I forgot to tell, i have a resource, and i return this

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        //return parent::toArray($request);
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'devicetype' => $this->devicetype,
            'value1' => $this->value1,
            'value2' => $this->value2,
            'value3' => $this->value3,
            'manufacture' => $this->manufacture,
            'devicemodel' => $this->devicemodel,
            'remark' => $this->remark
        ];
    }
```

if i do only `return parent::toArray($request);` it works.

Comment: Try `Device::with([ 'Devicemodel.Manufacture', 'Devicemodel.Devicetype' ])`

Comment: Still get null :(

Comment: Show your relationship code, model code.

Comment: `Device` hasOne relationship with `Devicemodel`?

Comment: try to call the `->toArray()` function on your relations: `$this->manufacture->toArray()` (not sure if you need the () behind manufacture :)). And are your sure `$this->manufacture` is set within your resource, dd it and make sure it is set.